# why does ticket spinlock .h file not compiled by kernel?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I use linux-2.6.31.8 as my kernel environment. Now I need to make some modifications of the ticket spinlock in the kernel. But to my surprise, the ticket spinlock.h file isn't compiled by the kernel at all. I check this by adding some illegal C statements and non compile error encounter. The test code i use is below:

```
#include <asm/atomic.h>
#include <asm/rwlock.h>
#include <asm/page.h>
#include <asm/processor.h>
#include <linux/compiler.h>
#include <asm/paravirt.h>
test /an invalid statement, but none errors/
/*
 * Your basic SMP spinlocks, allowing only a single CPU anywhere
 *
 * Simple spin lock operations.  There are two variants, one clears IRQ's
 * on the local processor, one does not.
 *
 * These are fair FIFO ticket locks, which are currently limited to 256
 * CPUs.
 *
 * (the type definitions are in asm/spinlock_types.h)
 */

#ifdef CONFIG_X86_32
# define LOCK_PTR_REG "a"
# define REG_PTR_MODE "k"
#else
# define LOCK_PTR_REG "D"
# define REG_PTR_MODE "q"
#endif
```

Any help plz. Thank you~~

Comment: A header file isn't compiled if it is unused. Include it in a .c file and try to compile it.

Comment: @nouney:What I googled is ticket spinlock is used in  linux kernel since version 2.6.25

Comment: @Charles0429 Are you specifying x86 32-bit architecture?  Abstracted spinlock.h is normally included as <linux/spinlock.h>, which will include arch-specific functionality from the <arch/foo> dir.

Comment: @PeterL. I'm using x64_64 architecture. I think the problem is caused by the config file of the kernel. Maybe I have set a item that override the default ticket spinlock, but I don't know how to find out it, could you give me some advice?

Comment: @Charles0429 Kernel config file problems can sometimes be a nightmare to figure out, at least it seems that way to me.  Try to find out which config file is being picked up by doing what you have done.  Put error messages in if you have to and see what CONFIG_* options are being turned on or not.  Maybe also take a step backward and see/copy a config file which correctly compiles for x86_64 arch.

Answer (score 0):

Header files aren't compiled unless some .c files include them.

Kernel heavily depends on configuration, which specify which files to compile. Maybe, with your configuration no-one compiled file uses this spinlock.

To find out, you could grep for files, which include this header. Then, you should spot, whether they are compiled. You could use makefiles to discover config option this file compilation depends on. Then, you could enable this option and get your desirable error.

Edit:

**Note:** Your kernel will not use any spinlocks if you build it without SMP.

Comment: What I googled is that ticket spinlock is the default spinlock in the x86_64 architecture in linux-2.6.31.8. But I don't know which item makes the kernel not use the default ticket spinlock, while use other spinlock. How can I find out where the setting in the .config file should I unset to "NO"?

Comment: In fact, all the second part of my answer describes it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The second part you wrote is a bit difficult for me, I'm a kernel beginner. Is there some simple ways to find out how to use ticket spinlock in the config file ?

Comment: (I'm a beginner, too. And that is only way I know.) Look at `include/linux/spinlock.h`. There is line `#ifdef CONFIG_SMP`. And this is real place, where kernel decides, what spinlock to use. If kernel multithreading is turned off, there is no need at spinlocks, and file with placeholders will be included.

Comment: I find that when I compile xen in the kernel, then the ticket spinlock is not compiled in the kernel.